# How to stop visiting back pages after logout

Tags: php

I have a problem when user login its perfactly fine and when he logout I am trying to destroy the session and stop him to visit the pages by clicking back button but it does not working user logout but when I click brower's button he still able to perform the task by clicking back button even he logged out.

This is my form code: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php

```
<div class="center">
    <form name="myForm" method="post" action="../Admin/AdminData.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
        <label>User name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="User">
        <br>
        <br>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="login_Admin" value="login">               
    </form>
</div>
```

On click submit button following code get executed: ../Admin/AdminData.php

```
if (isset ($_POST['logout'])) {
    $dbname->logout();
}
```

and call the following function:

```
public function logout() {
    unset($_SESSION["dbuser_name"], $_SESSION["dbpassword"],   $_SESSION["dbid"]);
    session_unset();
    Session_destroy();
    header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
    exit();
}
```

This is Admin's login code:

```
public function loginAdmin($login_admin) {
    if (!empty($login_admin[0]) || !empty($login_admin[1])) {
        $query = "SELECT Patient_ID FROM Patient WHERE Patient_name  = '$login_admin[0]' and Patient_password = $login_admin[1] and Role = 'a'";
        //var_dump($query);
        $abc = $this->conn->query($query);
        $row = mysqli_num_rows($abc);

        if ($row == 1) {
            while ($row1 = $abc->fetch_assoc()) {
                $_SESSION["dbuser_name"] = $row1['Patient_name '];
                $_SESSION["dbpassword"] = $row1['Patient_password'];
                $_SESSION["dbid"] = $row1['Patient_ID'];
            }
            header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/Admin_Index.php');
        } else {
            header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
        }
    } else {
        header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: some browsers keep the previous pages in cache and don't query the server again when using the back button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to prevent users from visiting pages without being logged in, what you need to do is check if a user is actually logged in.

For example:

```
// Prevent unauthorized users from visiting this page
if (!$_SESSION['dbuser_name']) {
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
}
```

**Note** The `exit;` after the `header(...)` prevents the script from executing further. There are methods to prevent your browswer from following redirects. The `exit;` makes sure that your users will not be able to see any page content without being logged in.

Also, when a user logs out, make sure you clear all it's data:

```
if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
    session_start();
}

session_destroy();
unset($_POST);

header("Location: login.php");
exit;
```

This will most probably fix your issue.

**Another note** I would like to advise you not to store a user's password in your session.

Answer (score 0):

Use Meta Tag for No-Cache

```
<meta Http-Equiv="Cache-Control" Content="no-cache">
<meta Http-Equiv="Expires" Content="0">
```

Answer (score 0):

main file Ex. index.php OR header.php write to below code

```
if(!$_SESSION["dbuser_name"])
{
    header('Location: login.php');
}
```

Comment: Get in a habit of adding `die;` after a `header('Location: ...`.

Answer (score 0):

in top of your Admin_Index.php add this code.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['dbuser_name']) || !isset($_SESSION['Patient_password']) || !isset($_SESSION['Patient_ID'])) 
{
    header('Location: ../FrontEndFiles/AdminLogin.php');
    exit();
}
```

this will redirect you to login page.. if the user log's out and tried to enter your Adminlogin.

Answer (score 0):

Add this function to your functions.inc.php or any file that you load with all your scripts:

```
function isAuthorized(){
    if (isset($_SESSION) && isset($_SESSION['dbid'])){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And on every page where authorization is needed you just do:

```
if (!isAuthorized()){
    header("Location: login.php");
    die(); // Stop the script! Browsers can choose to ignore the redirect.
}
```

You can choose to do the redirect and die() within the isAuthorized function.. its up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this in PHP code, at the top of each page, check that user is logged in OR not, If Not redirect to login page

```
<?php 
      if(!isset($_SESSION['isLogged'])) : 
      header("Location: login.php");  
?>
```